# Is there a rule for what we can turn into a compound modifier/adj?

Tags: modifiers, compound-adjectives

Consider the following:

> The music was perfect for a windows-down, summer's-day car ride.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? The hyphen usage looks particularly odd, but since they are being used as compound adjectives, I was under the impression it was be correct.

Comment: There are syntactic rules for English that preclude word combinations that no native speaker would find understandable; there are syntactic rules that exclude sentences from standard English.  But you're really asking a semantic question -- do your compound adjectives make sense?  They seem to me not only understandable, but graceful.  As opposed to "a bone-mineral, vulcanized-glacier car ride."  I think we'd both nix that.  But not on syntactic grounds.

Comment: Should have also mentioned what prompted this question. I wrote "wearing often minimalist designs" and Microsoft Word wants to correct this to "wearing often-minimalist designs", which, judging by a quick Google search, is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation, including hyphenation, is a matter of style.  Thus you should be guided by your manual of style. I use *The Chicago Manual of Style*, which gives a table of examples and rules to guide its proponents on hyphenating compound nouns and adjectives.  Here you will find what to do with "word of relationship + noun" like *brother officer* (leave open) and "adverb other than the *-ly* type + participle or adjective" like *often-minimalist* (hyphenate before the noun it modifies).

Your novel compounds don't have a place in the table, so your own judgment must be the guide.  It seems a good choice to me to hyphenate to emphasize the compound nature of the novelties, but that's just me.

Comment: So the Chicago Manual does actually advise to hyphenate "often-minimalist" before the noun it modifies i.e. "often-minimalist designs"? If that is the case then so be it.

Comment: @cors85 *CMS* lists some forms by name (e.g., *ex-*) and others by rule.  *Often-minimalist* is covered by the latter, which prevents the reader from associating the adverb with a nearby verb, as in "wearing often."  You seem depressingly resigned (*ly-*+participle) to the hyphen in this case, but *CMS* is just a guide.  If you're not writing for someone who insists you use it, you're free to adopt another more to your taste.